# Issue executing Java Code: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: java, java-io, fileinputstream

All -

I am having trouble figuring out why my code is not executing .  I've read multiple forums about moving the .java files to be out of the SRC and even creating the .txt files as a peer to SRC.  Here is my code and the error on the bottom:

```
package Part2;
   import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test { 

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String inputFileName = "data.txt", input;
        FileReader fileReader = null;
/**
 *  Create the FileReader  
 */
        try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(inputFileName);  

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
/**
 * Use the BufferedReader class to read the data.txt file
 */
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
/**
 *  Read the contents of the text file one line at a time using a loop
 */
        try {
            input = reader.readLine();
            while (input != null)
            {
/**
 * Invoke processInputData method for each line read.               
 */
            processInputData(input);
            input = reader.readLine();              
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
/**
 *  Close the input
 */
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    }//End of main method

/**
 * Write a private method processInputData which processes its string
 * input argument
 */
    private static void processInputData(String data) 
    {
/**
 *  Tokenize the string argument using the StringTokenizer class
 *  using the comma as the delimiter.
 */
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(data,","); 
/**
 * Iterate over the tokens
 */
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
/**
 * Extract the name token. Create a Student object and assign
 * to the variable currentStudent.          
 */
        String student =  st.nextToken();
        Student currentStudent = new Student(student);
/**
 * Read each homework grade token one token at a time. Use
 * the corresponding set method on the student object to set
 * the instance value.                      
 */
        int h1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        currentStudent.setHomework1(h1);

        int h2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        currentStudent.setHomework2(h2);

        int h3 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        currentStudent.setHomework3(h3);

        int h4 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        currentStudent.setHomework4(h4);

        int h5 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        currentStudent.setHomework5(h5);

        int h6 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
        currentStudent.setHomework6(h6);
/**
 * Display the string representation of the currentStudent object
 * to the console.          
 */
        System.out.println(currentStudent);
    }
  }
}

Error from Console:


    java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt (The system cannot find the file     specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where are you even opening `data.txt`? It isn't in this code.

Comment: The code you posted is not what is generating the `FileNotFoundException`.  Please post the relevant code.

Comment: It's looking or the file at the directory that the program runs from. If you're using an IDE, you should be able to check where this is. What I do, reverse the read and make it create a file. Then look for the file and you'll know where it's read/writing from (the directory I mean.)

Comment: Gotcha!  Ok I dont think this is an issue anymore.  Thanks guys!